# How should I read functions like this

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not a mathematician but I have a question about how I should read and understand function like this:

$$\begin{align}
\tau (n) &= |\{k : 1 ≤ k ≤ n ∧ k|n\}|;\\
\sigma(n) &= \sum\{k : 1 ≤ k ≤ n ∧ k|n\};\\
\sigma(n, a) &= \sum\{k^a: 1 ≤ k ≤ n ∧ k|n\};
\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As to the first expression, read it as the cardinality of the set of all positive integers $k$ such that $k$ is both less than or equal to $n$ and $k$ divides $n$

Comment: That kind of definition is both concise and extremely unfriendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part is the inner part:

> $\color{red}{\{\qquad\}}$ A set
>
> $\color{red}{\{k\qquad\}}$ of all $k$
>
> $\color{red}{\{k:\qquad\}}$ where
>
> $\color{red}{\{k: 1\leq k\leq n\qquad\}}$ $k$ is (inclusively) between $1$ and $n$
>
> $\color{red}{\{k: 1\leq k\leq n \wedge \qquad\}}$ and
>
> $\color{red}{\{k: 1\leq k\leq n \wedge k|n\}}$ $k$ divides $n$

That is just a very technical way of listing all divisors of $n$.

The first expression is the cardinality (size) of the set (=number of divisors of $n$), as the "absolute value" sign $|\ldots |$ has that meaning when you use it on a set instead of a number.

The second is the sum ($\sum$) of all divisors of $n$.

The last is the sum of all $a$-th powers of divisors of $n$.